# html.Button not worling with JupyterDash in Google colaboratory

Tags: button, google-colaboratory, dashboard, plotly-dash, html-components

I am trying to create a dashboard with a button to trigger actions in a dash within a google Colab notebook.

I have the following code which runs perfectly OK using Dash (in Pycharm):

```
import dash
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import dash_html_components as html


app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Button('Button 1', id='btn-nclicks-1', n_clicks=0),
    html.Button('Button 2', id='btn-nclicks-2', n_clicks=0),
    html.Button('Button 3', id='btn-nclicks-3', n_clicks=0),
    html.Div(id='container-button-timestamp')
])

@app.callback(Output('container-button-timestamp', 'children'),
              [Input('btn-nclicks-1', 'n_clicks'),
               Input('btn-nclicks-2', 'n_clicks'),
               Input('btn-nclicks-3', 'n_clicks')])
def displayClick(btn1, btn2, btn3):
    changed_id = [p['prop_id'] for p in dash.callback_context.triggered][0]
    if 'btn-nclicks-1' in changed_id:
        msg = 'Button 1 was most recently clicked'
    elif 'btn-nclicks-2' in changed_id:
        msg = 'Button 2 was most recently clicked'
    elif 'btn-nclicks-3' in changed_id:
        msg = 'Button 3 was most recently clicked'
    else:
        msg = 'None of the buttons have been clicked yet'
    return html.Div(msg)

app.run_server()
```

I have a [google colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/10lzNwgxoyaSXbnBJO8DTbW4oovzjq6WR?usp=sharing) where I use JupyterDash instead of Dash (as follows):

```
!pip install jupyter_dash
from jupyter_dash import JupyterDash
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import dash_html_components as html

app = JupyterDash()

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Button('Button 1', id='btn-nclicks-1', n_clicks=0),
    html.Button('Button 2', id='btn-nclicks-2', n_clicks=0),
    html.Button('Button 3', id='btn-nclicks-3', n_clicks=0),
    html.Div(id='container-button-timestamp')
])

@app.callback(Output('container-button-timestamp', 'children'),
              [Input('btn-nclicks-1', 'n_clicks'),
               Input('btn-nclicks-2', 'n_clicks'),
               Input('btn-nclicks-3', 'n_clicks')])
def displayClick(btn1, btn2, btn3):
    changed_id = [p['prop_id'] for p in dash.callback_context.triggered][0]
    if 'btn-nclicks-1' in changed_id:
        msg = 'Button 1 was most recently clicked'
    elif 'btn-nclicks-2' in changed_id:
        msg = 'Button 2 was most recently clicked'
    elif 'btn-nclicks-3' in changed_id:
        msg = 'Button 3 was most recently clicked'
    else:
        msg = 'None of the buttons have been clicked yet'
    return html.Div(msg)

app.run_server(mode='inline')
```

When I run it, I get a dashboard with three buttons, no error message but it does nothing when clicking the buttons. I would expect reciving messages such as: "None of the buttons have been clicked yet" (when launched) or "Button 3 was most recently clicked" after clicking button 3, for example.

Is it the case that buttons do not work in JupityerDahs?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it (based on this [colab](https://colab.research.google.com/github/plotly/dash-sample-apps/blob/master/apps/dash-chatbot/ColabDemo.ipynb#scrollTo=pPEkJcCxSqxs)).

```
!pip install -q jupyter-dash==0.3.0rc1 dash-bootstrap-components transformers
import dash
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
from jupyter_dash import JupyterDash

#app = JupyterDash()
# Define app
app = JupyterDash(__name__, external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP])
server = app.server

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Button('Button 1', id='btn-nclicks-1', n_clicks=0),
    html.Button('Button 2', id='btn-nclicks-2', n_clicks=0),
    html.Button('Button 3', id='btn-nclicks-3', n_clicks=0),
    html.Div(id='container-button-timestamp')
])

@app.callback(Output('container-button-timestamp', 'children'),
              [Input('btn-nclicks-1', 'n_clicks'),
               Input('btn-nclicks-2', 'n_clicks'),
               Input('btn-nclicks-3', 'n_clicks')])
def displayClick(btn1, btn2, btn3):
    changed_id = [p['prop_id'] for p in dash.callback_context.triggered][0]
    if 'btn-nclicks-1' in changed_id:
        msg = 'Button 1 was most recently clicked'
    elif 'btn-nclicks-2' in changed_id:
        msg = 'Button 2 was most recently clicked'
    elif 'btn-nclicks-3' in changed_id:
        msg = 'Button 3 was most recently clicked'
    else:
        msg = 'None of the buttons have been clicked yet'
    return html.Div(msg)

app.run_server(mode='external')
```